# Trying to identify certain pairs of data and isolate them

Tags: excel

For example if I have a set of data similar to what's listed below:

```
A B
1 2
7 8
5 4
7 5
6 8
1 4
5 1
7 3
```

My goal is to identify unique pairings  of data as it appears in rows. In the case of the above example I would want to identify pairings of 8 and 4. So for every row that has an 8 followed by a 4 on the next row, I want to identify it.

In addition to this I would like to separate these unique pairings from the main body of data. Either by exporting these unique pairings to a separate sheet OR just deleting the non-unique pairings altogether.

I've searched far and wide for a solution, but I've only found ways to identify duplicates and some column pairings.

Comment: Start with `=COUNTIFS(B$1:B$7, B1, B$2:B$8, B2)` in an unused column to the right. Fill down and then filter for **2** or **>1**. That should be enough to get you started. Come back and edit your question to include your own effort if you run into any more stumbling blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this IF(B2&B3="84","Yes",IF(B2&B1="48","Yes",0)) from C2 onwards.  The cells which contain "Yes" are the ones with 8 and followed by 4.  Hope it suits your requirement.